# OO-layout / formatting (like Wicket) in AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs, oop, angularjs-directive, wicket

I'm a pretty experienced Wicket developer, but curious about AngularJS, so I decided to give it a try. Most things are pretty straightforward when coming from Java (DI etc).

However, I was not able to find a (Object Oriented) strategy for layout of components in my page. In `Wicket`, you can pack view and behaviour together in a `Component`, for example a `Panel`. You can create multiple subclasses for a certain component, and decide which subclass to use in Java.

In my case, I develop a (abstract) `Game` which has a `Board` component. Based on the type of game, a different `Board` will be renderend. Other components, like the title bar, scoring, end-of-game animation etc. will be the same for all games. In `Wicket`, this would look something like this:

```
Board b = myGame.newBoardPanel(id);
add(b);
```

Where the game can provide an abstract method to provide a `Board`.

I tried looking at `views`, but it seems hard to combine multiple different dynamic components in them. In my case, next to the `Board`, I have an `AnswerPanel` which can also differ from game to game, but for some games, it will be the same.

My next move was to use `directives`; but it seems `AngularJS` is not designed to choose layout from the `controller`, as it is not easy to change (in my case) the `templateURL` to implement different layout.

**TL;DR**
What is the Angular way to implement different components in a OO-style?

Answer (score 2):

In angular you would use directives to reuse elements in the game.

Directives and element can have a controller associated with them. The controllers in angular are expected to be functions, which internally are instantiated using the `new` keyword, so you can use classes. And if you use classes you can use inheritance to share logic between your controllers.

You can modify the contents of a directive HTML node ($element), but you need to load and compile the template manually.

```
<!-- Use directives to reuse elements -->
<div ng-controller="GameController as gameCtrl">
  <title-bar title="gameCtrl.title"></title-bar>
  <answer-panel answers="gameCtrl.answers"></answer-panel>
  <!-- Pass data into your directives via attributes, from the controller -->
  <board type="gameCtrl.boardType"></board>
</div>
```

ES6

```
// controllers can be classes, as such they can be extended via mixins
// or OO extend.
class GameController {
  constructor($location, gameRepository) {
    var ctrl = this;
    var params = $location.search();
    gameRepository.get(params.id).then(function (game) {
       // store the data in the controller instead of the $scope,
       // this gives you context to where your data is coming from in 
       // the templates
       ctrl.title = game.title;
       ctrl.answers = game.answers
       ctrl.boardType = game.boardType;
    });
  }
}
```

The title-bar directive would be very simple:

```
function titleBarDirective() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    // this is a convenience for angular to associate the evaluation of the
    // element attribute 'title' to the $scope.title
    scope: {
      title: '='
    },
    template: '<span ng-bind="title"></span>'
  };
}
```

For the board, you can include your custom $compiled template, this might not work exactly but I hope it gives you a good starting point.

```
function boardDirective() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {
      type: '='
    },
    controller: BoardController,
    controllerAs: 'boardCtrl'
  };
}

class BoardController {
  constructor($scope, $element, $compile, $templateRequest) {
    var ctrl = this;

    ctrl.$scope = $scope;
    ctrl.$element = $element;
    ctrl.$compile = $compile;
    ctrl.$templateRequest = $templateRequest;

    // check for changes to the "type", because in this example the
    // type is coming from the gameRepository, so this directive could
    // be initialized before a request with the game type comes
    // from the server.
    $scope.$watch('type', function (newType) {
      if (!newType) return;
      ctrl._loadBoard(newType);
    });
  }

  _loadBoard(type) {
    var ctrl = this;
    // manually request the template
    ctrl.$templateRequest('/templates/board/' + type + '.html')
      .then(function (template) {
        // manually compile the template
        var boardTpl = ctrl.$compile(template):
        // manually add the link of the template with a scope to
        // the directive element
        ctrl.$element.append(boardTpl(ctrl.$scope));
      });
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the insight of modifying the default-compilation! I will read more into that.

Comment: Thanks, I learned a lot. Btw. in `BoardController` you need to assign $scope to ctrl.$scope else the $element.append line fails.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know about the missing variable assignment I have updated the answer.